# Spring integration aggregation issue after splitting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have developed an integration flow that simultaneously executes three flows. In the "flow3()" function, I am performing parallel API calls, where the number of calls depends on the size of the Address list. Each API request payload corresponds to an address within the Address block. The objective is to gather the API responses and associate them with the corresponding Address blocks in the AppDetails while preserving their order. This association ensures that each response is correctly assigned to the Address block at the corresponding index.

To illustrate, suppose the API response is: `{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false}`, and there are a total of four Addresses in the AppDetails (two for the first AppDetails and two for the second AppDetails). The desired outcome would be:

```
[[{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false},{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false}], [{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false},{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false}]]
```

Hence, we aggregate the responses into two separate arrays, one for each AppDetails. This arrangement facilitates looping through the responses later, making it easier to place the elements back into their respective Address blocks. If an AppDetails block does not contain any Address, the aggregator should provide an empty array for that specific AppDetails, indicating that no responses need to be added to that particular index. The critical requirement is to maintain the order.

However, there appears to be an issue with the provided code. When an AppDetails block lacks an Address block, the execution becomes stuck and does not proceed.

```
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(conditionToCallflow2, flow2())
                            .recipientFlow(conditionToCallflow3, flow3()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(gatherAndRespond()));
  }

  private IntegrationFlow flow3(){
    return flow -> flow.split("payload.AppDetails")
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .split("payload.Address",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true))
            .log("Address splitter")
            . channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .enrichHeaders(
                    h ->
                            h.header("consent-level", 0)
                                    .header("app-id", 0))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/data-call/data")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                    .extractPayload(true))
            .log("Address response: ")
            .aggregate()
            .log("1st aggregate")
            .aggregate()
            .logAndReply("final aggregator");
  }
```

Here is my input request:

```
{
    "AppDetails": [
        {
            "PId": 1230465,
            "AppNumber": 1,
            "Address": [
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                },
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PId": 126541,
            "AppNumber": 2,
            "Address": [
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                },
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ApplicationDetails": {
        "DataFlag": [
            {
                "flags": "4"
            },
            {
                "flags": "5"
            },
            {
                "flags": "7"
            }
        ],
        "CSTimestamp": "2022-11-08 10:39:09.382",
        "tsid": 991254996710
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]After Artem's suggestion I update my code -

```
private IntegrationFlow flow3(){
    return flow -> flow.split("payload.AppDetails",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true))
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .split("payload.Address ?: {}",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true).discardChannel(emptyAddressChannel()))
            .log("Address splitter")
            . channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .enrichHeaders(
                    h ->
                            h.header("consent-level", 0)
                                    .header("app-id", 0))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/data-call/data")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                    .extractPayload(true))
            .log("Address response: ")
        .aggregate()
        .resequence()
        .log("1st aggregate")
        .channel("mainAggregatorChannel")
        .aggregate()
        .resequence();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow emptyBlockFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(emptyAddressChannel())
            .transform(payload -> Collections.emptyList())
            .channel("mainAggregatorChannel")
            .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel emptyAddressChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
  }
```

But still for the below input request the flow is getting stuck somewhere -

```
{
    "AppDetails": [
        {
            "PId": 1230465,
            "AppNumber": 1,
            "Address": [
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                },
                {
                    "PostalCode": "TN1 1SS",
                    "Address1": "25 Ssdf",
                    "Address2": "Fsdf",
                    "Address3": "",
                    "Address4": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PId": 126541,
            "AppNumber": 2
        }
    ],
    "ApplicationDetails": {
        "DataFlag": [
            {
                "flags": "4"
            },
            {
                "flags": "5"
            },
            {
                "flags": "7"
            }
        ],
        "CSTimestamp": "2022-11-08 10:39:09.382",
        "tsid": 991254996710
    }
}
```

as you can see in the above input there is no Address block in the 2nd AppDetails.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look into this option of the splitter:

```
/**
 * Specify a channel where rejected Messages should be sent. If the discard
 * channel is null (the default), rejected Messages will be dropped.
 * A "Rejected Message" means that split function has returned an empty result (but not null):
 * no items to iterate for sending.
 * @param discardChannel The discard channel.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 * @since 5.2
 * @see DefaultMessageSplitter#setDelimiters(String)
 */
public SplitterEndpointSpec<S> discardChannel(MessageChannel discardChannel) {
```

This way you can directly send an empty array (list) to the channel where you can add an empty block into that `AppDetails`.

**UPDATE**

After discussion below we see now the logic required.

So, possible fix is like this:

```
.split("payload.Address",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true).discardChannel(emptyAddressChannel()))
...
.aggregate()
.channel("mainAggregatorChannel")
.log("1st aggregate")
.aggregate()

...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow emptyBlockFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(emptyAddressChannel())
        .transform(payload -> Collections.emptyList())
        .channel("mainAggregatorChannel")
        .get();
}
```

Pay attention how I inserted the `.channel("mainAggregatorChannel")` before top-level aggregator and after `Collections.emptyList()` transformer.

It doesn't matter where channel is declared you still can send message over there. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-channels.

Or you can extract that final aggregator with its input channel into a separate `IntegrationFlow` if you find that style more logical than have a dual behavior in one flow.

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out your `payload.Address` returns `null` and splitter in this case just drops message silently:

```
    Object result = splitMessage(message);
    // return null if 'null'
    if (result == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

You probably need to look into a function variant of the splitter:

```
.<AppDetail>split(p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getAddress()).orElse(Collections.emptyList()), 
     e -> e.applySequence(false).discardChannel(emptyAddressChannel()))
```

Or yeah, Elvis operator of the SpEL:

```
payload.Address ?: {}
```

Comment: Could you pls tell on which split() I need to use discardChannel ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking: I see only one in the code you share with us: `.split("payload.Address",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true))`

Comment: Oh! I see. You have another one: `split("payload.AppDetails")`. Well, it depends then which one can come without items to be really splitted.

Comment: I have implemented the discardChannel as you suggested, but it still does not handle the situation where there is no Address block for any of the AppDetails. I have made the necessary updates to the code in the post. Please take a look at it.

Comment: OK. We first of all need to understand which splitter are we talking about: the one for `AppDetails` or `Address`. And from there we will determine to which channel to send: after the first aggregator or the second one. If it is nested, then you still need to add that empty list as a part of the top-level aggregation. If the first `split("payload.AppDetails")` does produce an empty list, then you need to send a discarded message just after that second `aggregate()`.

Comment: NOTE: the `logAndReply()` is deprecated for a while already: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide#log-at-the-end-of-a-flow

Comment: Here the Address splitter can produce empty list, so are u suggesting to do something like this -        `.aggregate().<List<?>>handle((payload, headers) -> if (payload.isEmpty()) {return new ArrayList<>();  }  return payload; }).aggregate();`

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hello Artem, I have once again incorporated your suggestion into the post, but the issue of the flow getting stuck persists. It seems to be happening at the top-level aggregate() function because it prints logs up to the nested aggregate(). I am unsure if there is something I am overlooking.

Comment: It must not print those logs since you are discarding empty split. Or do you refer to something else?

Comment: So, since the address is not available for the second AppDetails, I would like the flow3() function to aggregate and return the following result: `[[{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false},{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false}],[]]`. As you can see, the second element is empty to indicate that there is nothing to insert for the second AppDetails since there is no address available. This way, I can iterate through this response and place each response back into the address block according to the flow3() response.

Comment: I assume that when I make the API call, each address element would be provided as a payload, and the response would be in the format of `{"name":"Jane Doe","favorite-game":"Stardew Valley","subscriber":false}`.

Comment: To address your inquiry, the flow encounters an issue within the flow3() function when there is an absence of an Address block in any of the `AppDetails`. However, if an Address block exists, the flow proceeds smoothly, aggregating the response and subsequently entering the `gatherAndRespond() `method within the gatherer.

Comment: Can you confirm, please, that the empty split really goes to the `emptyAddressChannel`? Then try to extract that `mainAggregatorChannel` into its own bean and use it instead of that name we have with your so far.

Comment: I tried to put a `.log()` inside `emptyBlockFlow()` and it seems empty split is not going there.

Comment: OK. Does your `payload.Address` SpEL expression return `null`? In that case splitter drops silently. Would be great if you can debug your project and place break point in the `AbstractMessageSplitter.handleRequestMessage()` to see what is going on when your `payload.Address` is executed.

Comment: It appears that the issue lies in the fact that the splitter drops when the address is null. However, since the sequenceSize is set to 2 and only one sequence is returned, the process gets stuck at the aggregator at the top level.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can achieve my requirement ?

Comment: See an UPDATE2 in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing the update. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that the code remains unchanged except for replacing the `.split("payload.Address",splitter -> splitter.applySequence(true).discardChannel(emptyAddressChannel()))` portion with `.<AppDetail>split(p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getAddress()).orElse(Collections.emptyList()), e -> e.applySequence(false).discardChannel(emptyAddressChannel()))` ?

Comment: That's correct. A `discardChannel` is triggered only if the result of splitter function is empty iterable. If that result is `null`, then message is dropped. So, you need to ensure in your spitter function that you return an empty collection instead. Therefore my suggestion in the end for your expression - `payload.Address ?: {}`

Comment: Thank you, Artem, for your assistance. I'm glad that your suggestion worked. However, there's another concern regarding the response order. As stated in the problem description, it is crucial to arrange the responses in the list while preserving the order of the ApplicantDetails and Address. In other words, if ApplicantDetails[0].Address[1] was utilized as a payload, the resulting list from the top-level aggregate() function must maintain this specific response order.

Comment: I have provided further details in the problem statement, and I would appreciate it if you could review it to confirm if it is clear and understandable.

Comment: For that purpose we suggest to use a `resequence()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#resequencer

Comment: I have included the .resequence() function, but the preservation of the order is still not happening. The order keeps changing with each call, and even after using .resequence(), the previous issue reappears, which is the program getting stuck when an AppDetails object doesn't have an Address block. Could you please review my updated post.

Comment: But I don't see that you use `payload.Address ?: {}`. The ordering problem has nothing to do with empty splitter result. The `.resequence()` must be before `.aggregate()` I'm not sure how you you decided that it has to be opposite...

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that, updated now.

Comment: Hello Artem, I have a slightly off-topic question. Is it possible for me to assign a string ("Status":"Failed") to a failed address request? For example, if `AppDetails[0].Address[0]` is successful but `AppDetails[0].Address[1]` fails, I would like `flow3()` to return `[{"Actual Response"},{"Status":"Failed"}]`.

Comment: I achieved this using Advice, pls let me know if u have any other suggestion.

Comment: This sounds like a different story. Please, consider to open a new SO question with respective details. See SO policies: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask